# Query dramatically slower with less rows from WHERE to evaluate

Tags: mysql, index, execution-plan

**What is the query**

```sql
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, laptime, driver_id, driverName
FROM (
   SELECT race_result_details.id id, driver_id, driver.name as driverName, laptime
   FROM race_result_details 
   LEFT JOIN races ON races.id = race_result_details.race_id
   LEFT JOIN `drivers` `driver` ON `race_result_details`.`driver_id` = `driver`.`id` AND driver.name != ""
   WHERE (
    `race_result_details`.driver_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND races.track_length_id = 2
    AND `race_result_details`.lap_number > 0 
    AND `race_result_details`.laptime > 3449 
    AND `race_result_details`.`timestamp` > 1197426432
   )
   ORDER BY `race_result_details`.laptime ASC 
   limit 100
) f
GROUP BY driverName 
order by laptime ASC 
LIMIT 10;
```

**What does it do**

It selects the best ranked racers based on their minimal laptime, showing maximum once per driver name.
It does so pretty well until I change the track_length_id to 2. Well, that should return faster, because we have less races with track_length_id = 2 right?

```
MariaDB > SELECT COUNT(*) FROM races WHERE races.track_length_id = 1;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    33396 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.038 sec)

MariaDB > SELECT COUNT(*) FROM races WHERE races.track_length_id = 2;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     7919 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.026 sec)
```

not really! Explain please.

**id 1**

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table               | type   | possible_keys                       | key     | key_len | ref                                         | rows   | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+---------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>          | ALL    | NULL                                | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                        | 100    | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    2 | DERIVED     | race_result_details | range  | race_id,timestamp,laptime,driver_id | laptime | 4       | NULL                                        | 598051 | Using where                     |
|    2 | DERIVED     | races               | eq_ref | PRIMARY,track_length_id             | PRIMARY | 4       | speeder_nette.race_result_details.race_id   | 1      | Using where                     |
|    2 | DERIVED     | driver              | eq_ref | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY | 4       | speeder_nette.race_result_details.driver_id | 1      | Using where                     |
+------+-------------+---------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

vs **id 2**

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table               | type   | possible_keys                       | key             | key_len | ref                                         | rows | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+---------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>          | ALL    | NULL                                | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                                        | 100  | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|    2 | DERIVED     | races               | ref    | PRIMARY,track_length_id             | track_length_id | 4       | const                                       | 7919 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    2 | DERIVED     | race_result_details | ref    | race_id,timestamp,laptime,driver_id | race_id         | 5       | speeder_nette.races.id                      | 23   | Using where                                  |
|    2 | DERIVED     | driver              | eq_ref | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY         | 4       | speeder_nette.race_result_details.driver_id | 1    | Using where                                  |
+------+-------------+---------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

So, I kinda see that the planner picked up a way which seemed like an optimal one and failed. I had some class about database systems in university but it's not enough to understand this correctly.

I've been trying to switch up the indexes in race_result_details table (but that doesn't seem to be a problem in the first place), swap the order of WHERE clauses (does it really matter? I feel like I remember instances where it did help, but that's probably related only to multi column indexes, am I right?).

The difference is huge, 0.011s to 3.5s

Is there a good way to trick the planner to pick the way it did for the first query?

**Edit:**

Tables (trimmed to minimal example):

```
CREATE TABLE `drivers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),     
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE `races` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID',    
  `track_length_id` int(11) NOT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),    
  KEY `track_length_id` (`track_length_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `race_result_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
  `race_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   
  `race_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `driver_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,     
  `lap_number` int(11) NOT NULL,      
  `laptime` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'real lap time',      
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),     
  KEY `race_id` (`race_id`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `laptime` (`laptime`),
  KEY `driver_id` (`driver_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `race_result_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`race_id`) REFERENCES `races` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `race_result_details_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`driver_id`) REFERENCES `drivers` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Changing LEFT JOIN to JOIN and deleting driver_id from the where didn't change anything at all.

Comment: It is hard to analyze without knowing which table each column is in.  Example:  `lap_number`.  Please qualify each column in the query and provide SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  That would also provide the indexes for us to critique.

Comment: Instead of testing `driver_id IS NOT NULL`, change the `LEFT JOIN drivers` to `JOIN drivers` ?

Comment: Edited to reflect the  important parts. Tried to give the minimal example of the tables AND fixed the query to be more explicit. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Is `lap_time` a typo for `laptime`?

Comment: Are there any other columns in `races`?  If not get rid of the table; it slows things down.

Comment: It's not actually, just a BC thing from the past. We have them both, but laptime is the thing that matters. There are actually around 40 in races, I just trimmed all the tables to make it easy to show what are these columns that matter with their indexes

Comment: What table is `lap_time` (with the underscore) in?

Comment: race_result_details, but why does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

So I did some last second googling after formuling the sentences which I wanted to ask and came up with an answer for one of them:

**Is there a good way to trick the planner to pick the way it did for the first query?**

Yes, there is! The index key used on the biggest table was "laptime" on the fast query. I am not sure why laptime (maybe it has the lowest number of values in it? Correct me if wrong please.)

It was just enough to add

```
FORCE INDEX (laptime)
```

just after FROM clause and it started to work lightning fast again. Yahoo! I keep this question here for future strugglers. I am still looking for somebody to answer more in depth response, which I will hopefuly get.

Comment: Beware: Index hints (such as `FORCE`) help today, but may hurt tomorrow when the data distribution changes.